# Generate a title with the name of the municipality with mouseover on a map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have seen many examples to paint a region with the mouseover function, but in my case I am unable to select a region. what am I doing wrong?

```
d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/finiterank/mapa-colombia-js/9ae3e4e6/colombia-municipios.json", function(error, co) {
      var subunits = topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios);
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
          .scale(2000)
          .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
          .center([-61,43])
          .rotate([2,3,2]);
      var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
      svg.append("path")
          .datum(subunits)
          .attr("d", path);
      svg.selectAll(".mpio")
          .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
          .enter().append("path")
          .on('mouseover', mouseover)

          .attr("class", function(d) { return "mpio " + "_" + d.id; })
          .attr("d", path)
          //.style("opacity",0);
      svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.mpios, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "mpio-borde")


      svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.depts, function(a, b) { return true; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "depto-borde");


      function mouseover(){
          console.log("here")
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1nchcd78/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that pointer events are enabled for your target layer (especially if you have no fill for them), and that svg features on top of your target layer do not have mouse events enabled:

```
pointer-events: all / none;
```

In your fiddle you assign event listeners to the .mpio selection:

```
 svg.selectAll(".mpio")
          .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
          .enter().append("path")
          .on('mouseover', mouseover)
```

But, you set pointer-events to none:

```
.mpio { pointer-events: none; ... }
```

This will never trigger. Instead, set pointer events to none for the other feature layers and set it to all for .mpio.

Now your event listeners will fire. Now all you need to do to is implement a basic tooltip. D3noob [has an excellent example here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369). I modified it only slightly to use it in the snippet below:

```js
var width = 900,
    height = 900;
    
var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
  .attr("class", "tooltip")    
  .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("https://cdn.rawgit.com/finiterank/mapa-colombia-js/9ae3e4e6/colombia-municipios.json", function(error, co) {
      
  var subunits = topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios);
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(2000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .center([-61,43])
    .rotate([2,3,2]);
  
  var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
    
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(subunits)
    .attr("d", path);
    
  svg.selectAll(".mpio")
    .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .on('mouseover', mouseover )
    .on('mouseout',mouseout)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "mpio " + "_" + d.id; })
    .attr("d", path)
    
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.mpios, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "mpio-borde")
    
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(co, co.objects.depts, function(a, b) { return true; }))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "depto-borde");

})

function mouseover(d){
  d3.select(this).style("fill","orange");
  div.style("opacity", .9) 
     .html(d.properties.name) 
     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")  
     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
}

function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).style("fill","steelblue");
  div.style("opacity",0);
}
```

```css
path {
     fill: #777;
  }

  .mpio {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-opacity: .25;
    stroke-width: .5px;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .mpio-borde {
    opacity: 0;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #00ff00;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
      }
  
    .depto-borde {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff0000;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-width: 1;
    opacity: 1;
      }
      
div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    width: 100px;     
    height: 28px;     
    padding: 2px; 
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
    background: white; 
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: aweasome! thanks. can you help me with anything easy for you? for example I have      <h1 id='department'></h1> , while I made mouseover in a department (region of line red) I want put the name of the department in h1 tag, document.getElementById("department").html(d.properties.name)

Comment: To change the content of an html element, try this in the mouseover function: `d3.select("h1").html("content")`. or, use a id/class identifier. Remember to set the content to empty or a default when the mouseout function is triggered. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wrczx1cw/

Comment: I know. But I did not understand, the municipalities are all subregions. The departments are the largest regions, those that are delimited with a red line. I want to do exactly the same thing that was done with the municipalities, but this time with the names of the departments.

Comment: You can't have mouseover events on two different svg layers that are ontop of each other - but you could access the department data that is contained in the municipality layer: `.html(d.properties.dpt)`

Comment: That was seeing, but my idea is to have a fill effect in one department and another on the municipality with mouseover. is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but was not apparent in your question. I am unable to answer now, but may be able later tonight. A new question might get you a faster response from the wider community.

Comment: I hope you can hel me with this please.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640313/paint-the-apartment-and-the-town-of-different-colors-d3-js